# How to properly load resources in a website made mostly with ajax?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, resources

Is it better to load *ALL* my resources in my base layout/template view, or directly in the partial view I load in ajax?

Exemple:

_layout:

```
[...]

    <head>
        <script src="file.js"></script>
        <link href="file.css"></link >
    </head>

[...]
```

**OR**

_layout:

```
[...]

    <head>
    </head>

[...]
```

partialView (loaded later in AJAX):

```
<div>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    <link href="file.css"></link > 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would normally be doing is pushing some script resources into a list on the viewbag, and then get your template to go through that list and generate the script include for you.

On the partial:

```
@{
    ViewBag.ScriptIncludes = ViewBag.ScriptIncludes ?? new List<string>();
    ViewBag.ScriptIncludes.add("script1.js");
}
```

In the layout (_Layout.cshtml)

```
@if (ViewBag.ScriptIncludes != null)
{
    foreach (string url in ViewBag.ScriptIncludes)
    {
        <script src="@url" type="text/javascript"></script>
    }
}
```

In normal circumstances this allows you to associate scripts with partial which is quite nice, and is a good idea if you are only refreshing a partial which exists on the page on page load.

The scripts should be preloaded on the page. You shouldn't be reloading scripts by getting a script resource via ajax and injecting it into the page. Ideally you wouldn't be getting html over ajax either, but some people find this acceptable. You only want to inject the html into the page and not more scripts. If you have event handlers on the items inside the partial view, consider attaching the event handlers to the container instead of the elements individually.

However, given that you are reloading potentially any view, I think you are better off including your scripts in the head. This will ensure that you don't find any conflicting scripts later on. Your site is essentially an application that costs the user a small overhead to load initially but does not need to be refreshed.

Comment: The problem is that all my website is in AJAX. Almost any view COULD be loaded.

Comment: What's the point of ajax if you are reloading everything anyway? If you preloaded _all_ your resources on the page prior to this then it might make sense. You have to be really careful with the JavaScript state. It's probably better to code your site such that all scripts are included in the head (better yet a single js file) so that you know that there are no conflicting states somewhere down the line. Also try not to break the back button ;)

Comment: I should probably mention that dynamic script loading is not bad but you need a more structured mechanism than just getting a partial view with some script includes in it. You would be looking more towards getting json data for each page and rendering it on the client, and loading javascript modules asynchronously.

Comment: I'm not saying that I will reload everything (at least, not a the same time...) and I'll not break the back button since I am using backbone.js for the routing!

Answer (score 1):

I think its depend on your context. lets say if you want to have a resource which needs for all the pages(views) its better if you put them in the layout. And again if you have a resource very specific to a view you can load them in the views.
And make sure that you are using URL helpers to get the url of resources. Otherwise you will have problems after deployment.

Comment: If I load my view "x" which have a script "y" and load it multiple times (overwriting the old one), is'nt it bad?

Comment: Ya , Its bad. If it is relevant for several views you need to load it from the template.